# Find an equation of the tangent line to $y = \cos(x)+3\sin(x)$ at $x=\pi/3$

Tags: calculus

> Find an equation of the tangent line to 
>   $$y = \cos(x)+3\sin(x)$$ at $x=\pi/3$.

This is what I have done...

Find $y$, $y= \cos(\pi/3) + 3\sin(\pi/3)$
this equals $1 + \sqrt 3/2$

Next

Find $f'(x) = \sin(\pi/3) + 3\cos(\pi/3)$
this equals $3+ 3\sqrt3/2$

Next

Plug into point slope form

$(y-1+\sqrt 3/2) = (3 +3\sqrt3/2) (x - \pi/3)$

$y = \left(\frac{3+3\sqrt 3}{2}\right)(x-\pi/3)+(1+3\sqrt 3/2)$

Am I doing something wrong? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, there is a mistake. When you put in point slope form, there needs to be a minus, not a plus in front of that radical (Distributive property)

Comment: That edit makes things lots easier for the eye...:)

Comment: Use `$f'(x) = \sin(\pi/3) + 3\cos(\pi/3)$` to show $f'(x) = \sin(\pi/3) + 3\cos(\pi/3)$. Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: I believe your evaluations of the trigonometric terms are incorrect: please check your results for the value of the function and its derivative.  It looks like you've swapped sine and cosine values, at the least. Also, _what_ is the derivative of $ \ \cos x \ $ ?

Comment: Note that $f'(x)=-\sin x+3\cos x$. There are  other errors, and several missing parentheses.  The general strategy is fine.

Comment: ok thanks I will work on it some more.

Answer (score 0):

While your strategy is correct, you incorrectly evaluated the sine and cosine functions at $x = \pi/3$ and incorrectly took the derivative.

Let $f(x) = \cos x + 3\sin x$.  Since 
$$\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{3}\right) = \frac{1}{2}$$
and 
$$\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{3}\right) = \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$$
when we evaluate $f(x)$ at $\pi/3$ we obtain

> $$f\left(\frac{\pi}{3}\right) = \cos\left(\frac{\pi}{3}\right) + 3\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{3}\right) = \frac{1}{2} + \frac{3\sqrt{3}}{2} = \frac{1 + 3\sqrt{3}}{2}$$

Since the derivative of $g(x) = \cos x$ is $g'(x) = -\sin x$ and the derivative of $h(x) = \sin x$ is $h'(x) = \cos x$, the derivative of $f(x)$ is

> $$f'(x) = -\sin x + 3\cos x$$

Thus, the derivative of $f(x)$ evaluated at $\pi/3$ is

> $$f'\left(\frac{\pi}{3}\right) = -\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{3}\right) + 3\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{3}\right) = -\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} + \frac{3}{2} = \frac{3 - \sqrt{3}}{2}$$

Hence, the equation of the tangent line is

> $$y - \frac{1 + 3\sqrt{3}}{2} = \frac{3 - \sqrt{3}}{2}\left(x - \frac{\pi}{3}\right)$$